# MPRemoteCommandCenter Not displaying in lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

May be it's a duplicate question, but none of the solutions working for me. I have tried out almost everything.

The now playing info is not getting updated in lock screen.

Swift Version : 5 &
iOS Version : 13

Here is my code

```
func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        

        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { event in
            return .success
        }
        

        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { event in
            return .success
        }
        

        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { event in
            return .success
        }
        

        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget { event in
            return .success
        }
    }
    
    func updateLockScreen() {
        var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = "Artist"
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "title"
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
```

One method is getting called from viewDidLoad i.e

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AudioManager.shared.audioManageDelegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setupRemoteCommandCenter()
    }
```

And other one is getting called from playbuttonAction method i.e

```
@IBAction func togglePlayPauseButton(sender: UIButton) {
        //play pause button
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        //updateLockScreen() //I checked it from calling here also
        if sender.isSelected {
            AudioManager.shared.playMusic()
        } else {
            AudioManager.shared.pauseMusic()
        }
        updateLockScreen()
    }
```

My Appdelegate is here

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        setUPforbackground()
        return true
    }

    func setUPforbackground() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Calling the `updateLockScreen()` before calling `playMusic()` also no result. Do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 0):

After analysing code carefully I have found that

`try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])`

Throwing error So I have changed it to below

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
```

Hope it will help someone. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason, your answer received a downvote. I don't quite understand it because, in a way, you're correct. Removing the option '.mixWithOthers' from the configuration of your audio session resolved the issue. This option allows your app to play audio simultaneously with other apps. By removing this option, your app gains full control over audio focus and can display the Remote Command Center properly without being disturbed by other apps.